# The extract source does not contain the specified extract field

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to extract `Month` and `Year` from `StartDate` filled which is `VARCHAR2` (*I know that is very big mistake but It's not my failure*) and whatever I try I always get error. I notice that problem is in `STARTDATE`

I have query something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(DAYS) absenceDays
  FROM user_timesheets_absence
 WHERE UserID = 348
   AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM to_date(StartDate)) = '2020-02-06'
   AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM to_date(StartDate)) = '2020-02-06'
   AND Approved = 1
```

I check a couple of post here in Stackoverflow and whatever I try I get error message

[First Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58947840/ora-30076-invalid-extract-field-for-extract-source)

[Second Post](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01861.php#:%7E:text=You%20could%20correct%20the%20SQL,string%20that%20you%27ve%20specified.)

As you can see I add `TO_DATE` field but however I always get error

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
           the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
           "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
           with no extra whitespace.
*Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.
```

One notation also the format of date is `'YYYY-MM-DD'`

Anyone how can tell me what I made wrong here ? Where the problem comes from ? Is `VARCHAR2` problem ?

Comment: If the values are strings like `'2020-02-06'`, then couldn't you query `where startdate like '2020-02-%'`? Do you really need all the datatype conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract doesn't return what you posted.

If `startdate` is `yyyy-mm-dd`, then convert it to date using `to_date` with appropriate format mask. Extract returns *month* or *year*, not the whole "string":

```
SQL> with test (startdate) as
  2    (select '2020-09-03' from dual)
  3  select to_date(startdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd') col1,
  4    extract(month from (to_date(startdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))) col2,
  5    extract(year  from (to_date(startdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))) col3
  6  from test;

COL1           COL2       COL3
-------- ---------- ----------
03.09.20          9       2020

SQL>
```

In your case:

```
and extract(month from to_date(startdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd')) = 6
and extract(year  from to_date(startdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd')) = 2020
```